# Arduino IR receiver and loops

Tags: arduino

so i built a small shield for arduino mega. it has 2 red leds, 2 blue leds, 2 green leds, a buzzer, an rgb led and an IR receiver. Im trying to simulate ON and OFF with the rgb led, and when it is on you can perform actions based on the button you press on the emitter. Everything works more or less as expected but i dont know how to exit the loop on each button action. Here s my code:

```
int receiver = 9;
IRrecv irrecv(receiver);     
decode_results results;       

void translateIR() 
{

   switch(results.value)
  {
  case 0xFFA25D: power(); break;  
  case 0xFF30CF: button1();    break;
  case 0xFF18E7: button2();    break;
  case 0xFF7A85: button3();    break;
  case 0xFF10EF: button4();    break;
  case 0xFF38C7: button5();    break;
  case 0xFF5AA5: button6();    break;
  case 0xFF42BD: button7();    break;
  case 0xFF4AB5: button8();    break;
  case 0xFF52AD: button9();    break;   

  default:;
  }

}    

void button1()
{
  digitalWrite(LEDR1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDR2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDB1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDB2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);

  do{
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
      delay(200);       

  } while(1);
}



void button2()
{
  digitalWrite(LEDR1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDR2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDB1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDB2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);

  do{
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
      delay(50);         

  } while(1);
}      

void loop() {  

  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // have we received an IR signal?

  {
    translateIR(); 
    irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value
  }  

}
```

With this code cannot exit the loop on button 1 and button 2 no matter wath other button i press after. So I tried adding this on the loop:

```
do{
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
      delay(200);  

      if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // have we received an IR signal?

      {
         translateIR(); 
         irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value
      }  

  } while(1);
```

But still cannot exit the loop no matter what button i press. Then i tried adding this on the while:

```
do{
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LEDR1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDR2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDB2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
      delay(200);        

  } while(!(irrecv.decode(&results)));
```

But it doesnt exit the loop either. Any idea?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program! Not only is this likely to get you in trouble if you're posting your employer's code, it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem....

Comment: thanks, i'll try to delete not important details.